# Array with unknown dimension number and unknown size dimensions at compile time in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have to work with arrays of which the number of dimensions and the size of each dimension are not known at compile time.
I wrote this code to do some tries :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int array_dim_size[16];
  int dim_nb=0;
  int coord[16];
  
  // Enter dimension sizes
  while (dim_nb<16 && scanf("%d",&array_dim_size[dim_nb]) && array_dim_size[dim_nb]!=0) dim_nb++;
  
  // array_dim_factor used to convert x dim coord to 1D dim coord
  int array_dim_factor[dim_nb];
  array_dim_factor[0]=1;
  for (int i=1; i<dim_nb; i++) array_dim_factor[i]=array_dim_factor[i-1]*array_dim_size[i-1];
  
  // Enter coordinates (no ckeck done because it is a very simple example)
  for (int i=0; i<dim_nb; i++) scanf("%d",&coord[i]);

  // Conversion from x dim coord to 1D dim coord
  int coord1D;
  coord1D=0;
  for (int i=0; i<dim_nb; i++) coord1D += array_dim_factor[i] * coord[i];
  printf("%d\n",coord1D);
  
}
```

To sum up,

1. Dimension sizes are entered at run time.
2. x dimensions coordinates are converted to 1D dimension.

I am sure this is not the right way to do that. It seems me that it is not C good practice.

What is the right way to code this program ? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Can you use `malloc` or make it the maximum possible size?

Comment: If you are allowed to work with C++ as well as C, then I would highly recommend `std::vector`. If not, you'll need `malloc`.

Comment: I use malloc to declare my array : `malloc (sizeof(int)*product of all dimension sizes)`. But it is a 1D array so I convert x dim coords with the code above. I do not know the maximum possible size .

Comment: @jramsey. I work with C and not C++

Comment: With an unknown number of dimensions, you pretty much have to do what you're doing. But, I'd put the requisite info into a `struct` and pass around a pointer to that. Something like: `typedef struct { int coord_count; int coord_index[16]; } coord_t; typedef struct { coord_t arr_dim; int *arr_data; };`

Comment: You have a limit of 16 dimensions. Also I see no `malloc` or`free` in the code. How will you determine at last the size of each dimension?

Comment: @arfneto I think his question is just about how to convert the n-D index into a 1D index, allocating the array itself is not an issue.

Comment: You can avoid the arbitrary 16-dimension limit by using `malloc()` for the `coord` array as well. Ask the user how many dimensions first.

Comment: Side Note: I'm not sure what the data you actually want to handle look like, but for 16 dimensions, each of size 4, with array elements of type `int32_t` you would require 16 GiB of storage.  That's quite large enough for concern.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. I agree. 16 is only an example.

Comment: It occurs to me that wanting 16 dimensions (or more) is for a simulation of "the quantum states of the multiverse" [using the phlogiston theory of matter, of course :-)]. For something like that, I'd think you're going to have a lot of "zero" or "don't care" elements, so you probably want a _sparse matrix_?

Comment: @CraigEstey. Sorry, not at all.

Comment: Seems like a dynamically-allocated `struct` with the raw numbers, as well as meta-information on how to interpret the number of dimensions, the sizes, would be best.

Comment: @Barmar you are rigth. But also from the author: _"I use malloc to declare my array : malloc (sizeof(int)*product of all dimension sizes). But it is a 1D array so I convert x dim coords with the code above. I do not know the maximum possible size"_ This is the origin of my comment...

Comment: My question has been tagged duplicated. In the answer, the same strategy is used  (there is only a slight difference : row major versus column major),. So, I concluded it is the right way to do that.  Just a comment, would it be possible to change the title of this question ? "How can i create an n-dimensional array in c" is not very informative.

Comment: @arfneto I think they meant "There's no specified maximum size" not "I don't know how to calculate the size."

Comment: @Stef1611 It's possible to edit the title, but what's wrong with that title?